# converting .webp to .jpeg using Java

Tags: java, webp

i want to  convert a .webp image to .jpeg. I have used `javax.imageio.ImageIO`.

but @ line no: 19 `bImage = ImageIO.read(fis);` returns a null for webp images.

Code is working fine if I try to convert .png ,.gif file format..

can any one help?

```
public static void imageIoWrite() {
    BufferedImage bImage = null;
    try {
        File initialImage = new File("resources/1.webp");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(initialImage);
        bImage = ImageIO.read(fis); //why it returns null?
        if (bImage != null) {
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg",
                    new File("resources/NewImage1.jpg"));
            System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("imag is empty");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured :" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the path to your file correct. Output `initialImage .exists()` and show if it is returning true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `ImageIO` is not able to read `webp` images. As you can read in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)), the method `read` returns `null` in this case. I think that you have to use an additional library to read and write `webp` images.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply..can you please let me know the library if you lnow any?

Comment: @DharmeshSojitra Google provides only a JNI wrapper for its C-library and I did not find a pure Java ImageIO plug-in. You can find more information about webp at [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/). There is also an [ImageIO plug-in](https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio) which uses JNI as well.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: There seems to be a fork here: https://github.com/sejda-pdf/webp-imageio